# Error when trying to sum the values with for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Every time is running it, was giving me time out! infinity loop. 
the error could be in my second loop but I already tried to make it outside and still giving an error.

Can't find the error, any help?

thank you

still having a problem to print the values, any help?

Im trying to get all the values and sum, after it print the sum with a new var.

```
college.Debug.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);


var workflow_value = [
    'Enter Value 1',
    'Enter Value 2',
    'Enter Value 3'
]

var questionsAndValues = {};

for (var i = 0; i < workflow_value.length; i++) {
    var fieldName = workflow_value[i];
    var fieldValue = college.getJobWorkflowValueByName(fieldName);
    if (fieldValue && fieldValue != '') {
        questionsAndValues[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    }
}

var values = [];
var sumOfValues = 0;


for (value in questionsAndValues){

    var current_value = parseFloat(questionsAndValues[value]);
    if (!isNaN(current_value)) {
        sumOfValues += current_value;
    } 
    else {
        console.log('invalid values');
    }
}

questionsAndValues['Total Value'] = sumOfValues;

var okShowText = function(){

};

var cancelShowText = function(){

};



$(document).ready( function() {

   college.Dialog.showProgressDialog('Loading Data...');

    for (var question in questionsAndValues){
        var rowToAppend =   '<div style="min-height:40px;border-bottom: solid 1px gray"><div style="min-width:38%; max-width:38%; display:inline-block; height:40px; border-right: solid 1px gray"><div style="padding:5%">' +  question + '</div></div>' + 
                            '<div style="min-width:60%; max-width:60%; display:inline-block; margin-left:5px"><div>' +  questionsAndValues[question] + '</div></div></div>'

        $('#detailsView').append(rowToAppend);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(questionsAndValues)); 
    console.log(sumOfValues);
    college.Dialog.hideProgressDialog();

        // console.log (sumOfValues);
    var options = {
        "title":"Total of values is",
        "text": "The total value is " + sumOfValues,
        "ok_label":"Yes",
        "cancel_label":"Do Nothing"
    }

    college.Dialog.showText("okShowText","cancelShowText",options) 

});
```

Comment: `var i = 0; i < workflow_value; i++` - did you mean to have `workflow_value.length`

Answer (score 1):

vars are scoped to the function, so all of your `var i`s are interacting with the exact same variable. So when an inner loop runs, it throws off the count of the outer loops. If you use `let` instead, then they'll have block scope and won't be trampling eachother.

After switching to let you'll still have an outer loop and the inner  loops using the same variable name. You should use different names for these, so that you don't get confused about which one is being accessed when

```
for (let i = 0; i < workflow_value.length; i++) {
  const fieldName = workflow_value[i];
  const fieldValue = college.getJobWorkflowValueByName(fieldName);
  if (fieldValue && fieldValue != '') {
    questionsAndValues[fieldName] = fieldValue;
  }

  const values = [];
  let sumOfValues = 0;

  for (let j = 0; i < workflow_value; j++) {
    const current_value = college.getJobWorkflowValueByNam(workflow_value[j]);
    values.push(current_value);
  }


  for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    const current_value = parseFloat(values[j]);
    if (!isNaN(current_value)) {
      sumOfValues += parseFloat(values[j]);
    } else {
      console.log('invalid values');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still having problem to print the values, any help?